# Passing an array to jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

so this is my problem:

I have this render function somewhere in my express code:

```
    function renderWithData(arrayOfEvents, res) {
    res.render("index", {
        locals: {
            pageTitle: "Wochenplaner",
            events: arrayOfEvents
        }
    });
}
```

it passes index.jade a variable called *events*.
Now i want to parse this variable inside of jade, for example like this:

```
- if(locals.events[0] == true) alert("Bla");
```

But express is telling me that *locals.events* is undefined.
How do i correctly pass a variable to that kinda "rendering-javascript"?

Comment: Have you tried just `- if (events[0] ...`?

Comment: Yes and this is obviously not working because events is a property of the locals object. So its telling me "events is not defined"
I also tried this: if(locals.events[i].time === i+7 && locals.events[i].day === 0)
Also not working, then it's telling me that time and day is not defined. But there is definitely data in events because when i print #{locals.events[0].day} in the html file there is the needed data!

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, first, I don't think you need the `locals` object, but that's a matter of personal taste. Second, it could e that `arrayOfEvents` isn't being passed, or is `undefined`.

Comment: Are you using express 3? If so, you shouldn't pass in the locals like that to `.render`. Just do `.render("index", { events: arrayOfEvents })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i'm a noob!

In my implementation this if-construct was cyceld through like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
if(locals.events[i].time == 7) alert("bla");
}
```

What i didn't consider was, that locals.events[i].time could be "undefined" because there simply wasn't a date at that index in that array.
So i fixed this by adding the following:

```
if(typeof locals.events[i].time !== "undefined" && locals.events[i].time == 7) alert("bla");
```

The right way to access and pass an js-variable from node-code to jade is to access it through the object. If this is my object:

```
locals: {
        pageTitle: "Wochenplaner",
        events: arrayOfEvents
    }
```

Then i would access it in Jade like this:

```
locals.events[index].property
```

Sorry for wasting your time :)